# Электронная цифровая подпись. Ruby

Tags: ruby, шифрование, цифровая-подпись

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

```
require 'openssl'
require 'digest'

rsa_key = OpenSSL::PKey::RSA.generate(2048)
loop do 
    p 'Input 1 to encrypt'
    p 'Input 2 to decrypt'
    p 'Input 3 to exit'
    print 'Input: '
    choise  = gets.chomp
    if choise.to_i == 1 
        private_key = OpenSSL::PKey::RSA.new File.read 'private.txt'

        file = Digest::MD5.hexdigest(File.read('text1.txt'))

        p file
        text = private_key.private_encrypt(file)
        p text

        File.open('text.txt', 'w') {
            |file| file.write(text)
        }
    elsif choise.to_i == 2

        public_key = OpenSSL::PKey::RSA.new File.read 'public.txt' 

        file = File.read('text1.txt')

        text = public_key.public_decrypt(file)

        p text
    elsif choise.to_i == 3
        break;      
    else
        p 'Incorrect input'
    end
end
```

1. Генерация пары ключей асимметричного шифрования (открытый ключ –
   закрытый ключ) алгоритма RSA
2. Экспорт и импорт открытого и закрытого ключей шифрования RSA в
   файл
3. Хеширование текста методами MD5 и SHA-1
4. Подпись документа следующих форматов: *.doc, *docx, *.txt
   Иначе говоря, осуществить шифрование закрытым ключом из п.1
   значения хэша из п.3
5. Экспорт подписи в XML-файл (или любой другой контейнер, на выбор)
6. Проверка подписи на основе импортируемого контейнера (в формате
   п.5) и подписанного файла. В случае несовпадения – программа должна
   показать соответствующее сообщение.

Записывает нормально, но когда хочем считать выдает ошибку:

```
C:/Users/jekak/Desktop/OZI_labs_1234/lab4/rsa.rb:29:in
`public_decrypt': padding check failed (OpenSSL::PKey::RSAError)    from
C:/Users/jekak/Desktop/OZI_labs_1234/lab4/rsa.rb:29:in `block in <top
(required)>'    from
C:/Users/jekak/Desktop/OZI_labs_1234/lab4/rsa.rb:5:in `loop'    from
C:/Users/jekak/Desktop/OZI_labs_1234/lab4/rsa.rb:5:in `<top
(required)>'    from -e:1:in `load'     from -e:1:in `<main>'
```

Answer (score 0):

Проблема оказалась в том, что название файлов должно быть text.txt просто